# SQL KEY Constraint Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, key

I understand the only SQL key constraints to be:

**UNIQUE** - each row for a column has unique value

**PRIMARY KEY** combo of NOT NULL and UNIQUE

**FOREIGN KEY** - Ensures data in one table to matches values in another table

What kind of key contraint is created by just using KEY syntax on its own? eg 
**KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)** in the below example.

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_id` VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
  `payment_status` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `payment_amount` DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `payment_date_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How hard is it to look this up in the manual?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Valid point; but to be fair, the answer to this question is not easily found with a simple web search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can
>   also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This
>   was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.